# Xcode 13 not showing iOS 14 simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios14, xcode13

I have downloaded some iOS 14 runtimes, and created some simulators with iOS 14. However, none of the iOS 14 sims appear in the list of run targets, meaning I can't run my app in them. The iOS 15 sims are working fine. I do see a bunch of iOS 14 simulators when I run `xcrun simctl list devices`.

I have tried Xcode 13.3 beta 2 and Xcode 13.2.1. The usual solutions like restarting Xcode and rebooting the Mac didn't help.